# Nontrivial lower bounds on a certain integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \in C^\infty(0,\pi)$ be a nonnegative function and suppose we know $\int_0^\pi f(\theta) \sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ and that $\int_0^\pi \cos(\theta)\, f(\theta) \sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta  = 0$. Is there a way to get a nontrivial lower bound on

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2(\theta)\, f(\theta) \sin(\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta \tag{*}$$

in terms of $\int_0^\pi f(\theta)\sin(\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta$?

Note that $\min_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} f(\theta)$ can be zero.

**Remark 1.** Actually, I also know that $f(\theta)$ is a rational function in even powers of $\tan(\theta /2)$, whose denominator is always $\geq 1$ but with arbitrary coefficients.

**Remark 2.** The power 2 of the sine in (*) can be any $k > 5/4$ but I'd like to keep it not too large.

Comment: I suggested some aesthetic edits to the integrands. Let me know if you disapprove $\ddot\smile$